# Why is USB stick not booting to update BIOS? Is this possible?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios, iso-image

I want to update the BIOS for a system.  I downloaded the latest ISO of the BIOS directly from the system's manufacturer.

I used Linux Mint's USB Image Writer to make a bootable USB stick of the ISO.  It created an ISO 9660 filesystem image on the USB stick (which itself is a portable USB stick reader with a 4GB SD card inserted in it).  I set the system to boot from USB first and to temporarily boot up using legacy CSM mode with Secure Boot disabled.  The system would not, however, boot from the USB stick.  I then switched to UEFI boot mode, but the system still would not boot from the USB stick.

Why would this not be working?  Could it be because the 4GB USB stick is much larger than the ISO's code would expect?  If so, would a reasonable course of action be to burn the ISO to a DVD-R or CD-R disc instead?  Unfortunately, only DVD-R's are in stock nearby, and I would like to get this done right away.  I'm concerned that I may run into the same issue if I buy a spindle of DVD-R discs, if the size of the target media could be the issue.  Or if there's a different likely issue, I would prefer to try to resolve that issue instead of buying a spindle of DVD-R discs.

Comment: Only ISOHybrid images can be used like that. This won't work. Try and get the BIOS update in another way.

Comment: @DanielB The system manufacturer only supplies the BIOS as an ISO.  They recommend burning it to a CD-R.  But I haven't had a CD-R since Taylor Swift was in diapers.  Give or take a few years. ;)

Comment: Have you tried using a plain USB drive? On some PC's, I've had boot from SD (and µSD) card fail sporadically.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a link to this BIOS update? We could then check the ISO and perhaps provide specific instructions on how to do it with a USB drive.